# I want to add Appium (Script)Recording & Playback Functionality in Project is it possible

Tags: automation, appium, android-testing, appium-android

as we know Appium has functionality to generate script for Mobile Testing. actually I want to to add this functionality in project. is it possible using java.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the functionality by yourself, probably build a full app.

Appium-Desktop is s Node.js application, if you are familiar with js you can get idea for implementation from [source code](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/blob/09e93b22340dad14c7a0a0893925a6ef3990c66b/inspector/app/renderer/lib/client-frameworks/java.js)